# mysqld: set max_connections to zero

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set `max_connections` value of mysql to `zero` or `null`, to test one of the case in my application and it is deployed in Linux environment.

setting `max_connections = 0` is reverting to `1` once service refreshed.

Is there any way to set `max_connections` to `zero` or `null` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12061/mysql-auto-adjusting-max-connections-values You should check mysql startup log and provide mysql version too

Comment: mention you are using LAMP or Linux environment.

Comment: Linux Environment @RahatHameed.